# Why time is showing incorrectly here?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have used NSDateFormatter to set dateFromString as below

```
NSString *string = @"Tuesday, February 3, 2015 10:54:39 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d, y hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"myDate is: %@", [myDate description]);
```

**Output is:** myDate is: 2015-02-03 17:24:39 +0000

Am I missing something here.

Comment: have you update your system time?

Comment: The 5.5 hour time difference suggests UTC (GMT) versus Indian Stretchable Time.

Comment: @Rob, I assumed that it will log the exact time from string without considering timezone(WYSWYG). Thanks for clarification. Also by saying "in your local timZone", do you mean,  whatever system default timeZone is set to. One implementation for all devices in different time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `NSLog` a `NSDate`, it will show you the date in GMT/UTC time (hence the `+0000`). This is because `NSDate` objects don't, themselves, capture the time zone, only a string representation of a `NSDate` object does. So assuming that this input string was in your local timezone, your formatter is correct.

If, though, this input string was really in GMT/UTC, but this string doesn't have anything in it to tell you that (e.g. a `+0000` or a `Z`), then you have to explicitly tell the the `NSDateFormatter` that you know that it wasn't necessarily a local timezone, but rather that you know that the original string was in a particular timezone, e.g.:

```
NSString *string = @"Tuesday, February 3, 2015 10:54:39 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE, MMMM d, y hh:mm:ss a";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:string];
```

Just remember that whenever you `NSLog` a `NSDate`, it will show it to you in GMT/UTC. If you want to show a `NSDate` in your local time zone, then use `NSDateFormatter` method `stringFromDate:` (without specifying a `timeZone` property of the formatter, thereby defaulting to you local timezone).

By the way, for additional considerations when parsing time zone from a web service, see [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). Notably, when parsing a date that you know is in Gregorian calendar, regardless of what calendar format the user is using, then you may also want to explicitly specify the `locale` of the formatter:

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

Answer (score 0):

your output date converted in UTC formate so you have to add time different between GMT time to UTC time as follow

```
NSString *string = @"Tuesday, February 3, 2015 10:54:39 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d, y hh:mm:ss a"];
NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMT];
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:string];
myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:currentGMTOffset sinceDate:myDate] ;
NSLog(@"myDate is: %@", [myDate description]);
```